# Forgot password system using Gmail & Laravel 8

Tags: html, laravel, authentication, web, gmail

I am using built in Laravel 8 login system with its scaffolding have a project that has a forgot password for its login system which sends emails from requests. I'm trying to use Gmail and XAMPP for sending the email. I am unable to send an email using the Gmail account,  So I tried configuring my `.env` and other configuration files in XAMPP. But I get the following error upon sending the request

```
Swift_TransportException
Connection could not be established with host smtp.googlemail.com :stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

Could someone tell me why I'm getting this error and what should I do to get rid of this? Thanks a lot.

```
<**env**>


MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=********@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=********@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"



<** php.ini**>
inside xampp\php\php.ini under the function  under the tab [mail function]

SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = ******@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"


<**sendmail.ini**>
inside xampp\mail\sendmail.ini under the function [sendmail]


smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=*******@gmail.com
auth_password=******
force_sender=*******@gmail.com
```

Comment: Gmails host  in your `.env` file is `MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com` it should be `MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com`

Comment: I changed  MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com to MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com but their is no change same error appears

Comment: I think this should help you [https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/34846#issuecomment-664830958](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/34846#issuecomment-664830958) The idea is similar: To use ssl use port 465 not 587.